# Does exist any kind of inverted if? in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have one dictionary and one string, and one function that i wanted to return "y", but for now could return "y" or "z":

```
import re

def find_my_keyword():
   dict_colour = {
        "x": ["back", "blue", "green"],
        "y": ["yellow", "white", "green"],
        "z": ["yellow", "white"]
        }
   str1 = "I have yellow, green and white"

   for colour, keywords in dict_colour.items():
        if all(re.search(kw, str1) for kw in keywords):
            return colour
```

Is there any way to add new array in my z list like not green:

```
"z": ["yellow", "white", =! "green"] ?
```

Or is any library to do exactly this function in python?

Comment: as a commentary, you don't need `re.search`, write just `kw in str1`

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? There might be better ways to solve this. Are you trying to find the key that have the most matches? What if you had a string like "I have yellow and white". Should that match y, z or both? or how about "I have white and blue"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I'd recommend something like this:

```
...
"y": {'has':["yellow", "white", "green"], 'hasnt':[]}
"z": {'has':["yellow", "white"], 'hasnt': ["green"]}
...

for colour, keywords in dict_colour.items():
    if all(kw in str1 for kw in keywords['has']) and not any(kw in str1 for kw in keywords['hasnt']):
        return colour
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change python syntax. But can get the desired result. Just adopt a convention e.g. not is represented by a `~` at the beginning of the keyword. Then you can do this:

```
def find_my_keyword():
   dict_colour = {
       'x': ['black', 'blue', 'green'],
       ...
       'z': ['yellow', 'white', '~green']
   }

   str1 = 'I have yellow, green, white'
   for key in dict_colour:
       if all(colour not in str1 if colour.startswith('~') else colour in str1 for colour in dict_colour[key]):
           return key
```

Comment: You can use `(colour in str1) ^ (colour.startswith('~'))` instead of the `if` expression.

Comment: True; but I think the `if` statement makes the logic very clear.

Comment: Thanks Jayanth Koushik, I tried it still returns the first key it finds, without care if ~ in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to create regex patterns that should not contain a specific word. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259443/how-to-match-a-line-not-containing-a-word) might be what you're looking for.
Try replacing `dict_colour` with

```
dict_colour = {
    "x": ["back", "blue", "/^((?!green).)*$/"],
    "y": ["yellow", "white", "/^((?!green).)*$/"],
    "z": ["yellow", "white"]
    }
```