# How to replace substring that's not enclosed in tags with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have sentences.

`text="The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. Obama was reelected president in November 2012".`

I want to put `<PERSON></PERSON>` tag in "Obama", so the result will be like this:
`The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. <PERSON>Obama</PERSON> was reelected president in November 2012".`

I want to find substring(example: Obama) that there is no tag `<PERSON>` before the substring and there is no tag `</PERSON>` after the substring, but I don't know the right syntax for regex in python.
**I'm new to python :''

With simple regex `re.sub(namedEntity, "<PERSON>"+namedEntity+"</PERSON>", text)` will give an output
`The president of America is <PERSON>Barack <PERSON>Obama</PERSON></PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. <PERSON>Obama</PERSON> was reelected president in November 2012".`

this is my code(using python2.7)

```
import re

result=re.sub(r"((?!<PERSON>).*"+namedEntity+".*(?!</PERSON>))","<PERSON>"+namedEntity+"</PERSON>",text)

print "result: "+result
```

The output
`result: <PERSON>Obama</PERSON>`
And I don't know that is the first "Obama" or the second one.

Thanks for your help before

Comment: Did you copied the code from somewhere ? Do you understand what you are doing in that regex ?

Comment: I tried the regex in https://www.regex101.com/#python by learn from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259443/how-to-match-a-line-not-containing-a-word . Maybe I'm wrong because I assume that ?!regex means "not contain regex" :''

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. In your new regex `r"((?!<PERSON>).*"+namedEntity+".*(?!</PERSON>))"`, you have `.*` before and after which matches 'Obama' with any characters before and after it and the lookarounds are ignored because the tags are in the matched group. If you remove them, you get the results you're after.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. Obama was reelected president in November 2012"
>>> namedEntity = 'Obama'
>>> result = re.sub(r"((?!<PERSON>)"+namedEntity+"(?!</PERSON>))","<PERSON>"+namedEntity+"</PERSON>",text)
>>> print result
'The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. <PERSON>Obama</PERSON> was reelected president in November 2012'
```

For future regex testing, regex101 works well to check how things work as you change them live. For your case [this](https://regex101.com/r/pK0dN7/1) shows what's happening.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(?<!<PERSON>)` i.e `negative lookbehind` ? I actually got confused there.

Comment: @noob, I don't think so. You want to ignore the matches that already have the tags around them.

Comment: Just an additional [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/8iLSjw) to show that this is the correct answer (+1).

Comment: Is that ?! and ?<! applied for look ahead and look behind exactly before and after the substring? Because went I try to "The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama Aaa</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. Obama Aaa was reelected president in November 2012". It gives the result "The president of America is <PERSON>Barack <PERSON>Obama</PERSON> Aaa</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. <PERSON>Obama</PERSON> Aaa was reelected president in November 2012" cc @Holloway

Comment: @KhusnaNadia, that's true, it relies on the tags being around the name.

Comment: Can I get <PERSON> that is not exactly on the left of the substring and </PERSON> that is not exactly on the right? I am not sure what keyword to search in Google about the syntax.

Comment: I think at that stage I'd look into parsing the text as XML rather than using regex. There are plenty of python xml libraries out there.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `.*` part in your regex-lookarounds.

```
>>>text="The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. Obama was reelected president in November 2012"
>>> surname=re.search(r'<PERSON>(.*)</PERSON>', text).group(1).split()[1]
>>> print surname
Obama
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!<PERSON>)'+surname+'(?!</PERSON>)', '<PERSON>'+surname+'</PERSON>', text)'  
The president of America is <PERSON>Barack Obama</PERSON>. He was born on August 4, 1961. <PERSON>Obama</PERSON> was reelected president in November 2012'
>>>
```

Note: you can also extract the surname of the person using regex and capture groups which i have captured in `surname` variable. You can use `(?<!regex)` to assert negative lookbehind and `(?!regex)` to assert negative lookahead