# Why do you have to mention the start and end characters in regex?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

The question was a regex that does not contain the letters PART. Here was an answer: 
/^((?!PART).)*$/

Link to question: [How to match a line not containing a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259443/how-to-match-a-line-not-containing-a-word/6259570#6259570)

My question is, why does it not work unless you indicate start(^) and end($)?
Why doesn't only ((?!PART).)* work?

Comment: The question you link to answers your question: "The ^ and $ anchors are there to demand that the rule be applied to the entire string, from beginning to end. Without those anchors, any piece of the string that didn't begin with PART would be a match. Even PART itself would have matches in it, because (for example) the letter A isn't followed by the exact string PART."

Answer (score 0):

The pattern

```
/^((?!PART).)*$/
```

matches the general pattern `^.*$`, namely anything occurring in between the start and end anchors.  However, it also contains a negative *assertion* `(?!PART)`.  As written, your pattern asserts that, at *each* position in the string, the string `PART` does not appear when looking forward for four characters.

If you just use this pattern:

```
/((?!PART).)*/
```

then it only means that `PART` does not occur at any certain point in the string.  But as [this demo shows](https://regex101.com/r/PGBtLl/2), a string such as `PART hello world` would match this alternative pattern, and may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because the concept of "line" means nothing without the "multiline" flag `re.M`. Also if you only match the part of the line containing PART then all of your matches will also be the string "PART" or in the example above "PART" + the entire remaining line (depending on flags).

`^` = start of line
`$` = end of line
`re.S` = DOTALL, a dot includes whitespace/end of line markers 
`re.M` = MULTILINE do not treat lineendings as match end

Without making that explicit you are only doing a substring matching and ignoring line endings entirely.